# Mysql MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE not working properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

In Mysql, I have items table with Title Column in it.
Of course, I added FullText Index to Title column.

When I try this query,

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH (Title) AGAINST ('#26' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It returns no results.

But when I try to do,

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE Title LIKE '%#26 %';
```

It returns me correct results, for example,

- 2018 Topps Living **#26** Yoan Moncada Rookie RC Gem Mint BGS 9.5
- 1986-87 Fleer Basketball **#26** Clyde Drexler RC Rookie HOF Mint PSA
  9

It's making me more confused because following MATCH AGAINST queries works fine

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH (Title) AGAINST ('RED' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH (Title) AGAINST ('#269' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Of course, I changed ft_min_word_len = 2 in mysql config.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you restart `mysqld` after changing `ft_min_word_len`?

Comment: @Barmar, Yes I did.

Comment: It seems like ```ft_min_word_len``` works fine only when there is no special character in the term. Because ``9.56`` doesn't work neither.